# How to identity the email is exists(valid) or not for yammer /invitations.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, email, yammer

I am Working on yammer API to Sends an email invitation to a user who has not yet joined the current user’s yammer network.

By using this [URL](https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/invitations.json)

In User Information:  After Sign In with my organization mail id it generate one token than passed the parameter of email (ddd@gmail.com) Here which i passed mail id is invalid, but status is "OK"
Here how to check  mail id is valid or not and exists or not in C# code can any one help me here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that a string is an actual, *valid* email address can be pretty complicated work, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address). You could have a minor check to ensure that you have an `@` followed by a `.` in your string.

Usually, what one does is to send a confirmation email with an activation link. Once that the user clicks the link, which contains some token, the application validates the account.

Comment: hi  i am Ensuring about string which i am passing  parameter(ddd@gmail.com)  but  before  user clicks the link,can we  know  validate the account. i.e  (invitation sent or not) ?

Comment: @stpdevi: So you want to ensure that the user's account exists before he/she signs up?

Comment: @stpdevi: I do not think that it is possible. Is there any particular reason you want to validate their account *before* they sign up?

Comment: yes we have plenty user so we want track the user for how many got invitation for reaming we will send by manually

Comment: @npiniti manully means from URL now we are sending through programmtically